# glsurfaceview inside a scrollview, moving but not clipping

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, clipping, glsurfaceview

I have a scrollview with a linear layout inside. One of the elements inside this linearlayout is a glsurfaceview.

This all works correctly and when I scroll the glsurfaceview moves up and down however when the glsurfaceview reaches the top or bottom of where it should of the scrollview where it should be clipped it is not and is continued outside of the scrollview. This screenshot should make it clearer:

[image: glsurfaceview not clipped correctly]

Don't think it's completly nessecary but here is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip"
>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <!-- LOTS OF SEEKBARS/TEXTVIEWS -->
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/glview"  
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="250px"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <!-- OK/CANCEL BUTTONS -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

All help much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @stealthcopter, did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosting SurfaceViews inside ScrollView (or Listview, etc.) is currently not supported.

Comment: Has anything changed regarding that fact?

Comment: You can now use a TextureView to achieve the desired effect. A TextureView lets you do what a SurfaceView does but will work inside scroll views (and can be animated, etc.)

Comment: @RomainGuy : Textureview works with scrollview but other views are not getting along with the textureview . Any inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use below lines for removing over scrolling :

```
glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

And for removing black background :

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
linearLayout.addView(glView);
```

Also add below line in your manifests file :

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not about support as answered abowe. The cause of issue is that `GLSurfaceView` is not on the view level. In short: for you case you have `GLSurfaceView` at the first level, then other views with `holes` in views abowe `GLSurfaceView` *(this handles by windows manager, and it dosent matter where you put `GLSurfaceView` on xml, it will be on first level in any case and others views on next level)*

So, what you need is to force view update, and there is work around: you should put scroll with `GLSurfaceView` or (RecyclerView with `GLSurfaceViews`) "between" two `FrameLayouts`. something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout   
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       ---- here should be linear layout with your glView, or RecyclerView instead if required ----
     </ScrollView>

   --- this frame also required: ---
   <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</FrameLayout>
```