# VideoView in CardScrollView Google Glass

Tags: android, surfaceview, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

According to Romain Guy's answer here:

[glsurfaceview inside a scrollview, moving but not clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134569/glsurfaceview-inside-a-scrollview-moving-but-not-clipping/5136012#5136012)

one should not use `SurfaceView` inside `ScrollView`, or `ListView`, etc.  Since `VideoView` is subclass of `SurfaceView`, I was wondering how this applies to `CardScrollView`?

Comment: There is also a comment: You can now use a TextureView to achieve the desired effect. A TextureView lets you do what a SurfaceView does but will work inside scroll views (and can be animated, etc.) - this should work in the CardScrollView as well

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and am looking into video with TextureView as we speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the proper way to do this is with a `TextureView`.