# GLSurfaceView disappear when Scroll up and scroll down again in RecyclerView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-recyclerview, glsurfaceview, rajawali

I attached my customize `GLSurfaceView` inside `RecyclerView's` Item layout. When I scroll up and scroll down again my `GLSurfaceView` is gone. I use Rajawali 3D engine for android OS.

This is my `ViewHolder` in `recyclerView Adapter`

```
class FieldViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ISurface customizeSurfaceView;
        CardView cardView;

        public FieldViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.customizeSurfaceView = (ISurface) itemView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
            this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewField);
            RendererClass rendererClass = new RendererClass(context);
            customizeSurfaceView.setSurfaceRenderer(rendererClass);
        }
    }
```

In my Logcat, I found those Error:

```
Could not link program in org.rajawali3d.materials.Material: 
Getting location of uniform: uModelMatrix returned -1!
E/Rajawali: Getting location of uniform: uTime returned -1!
```

and

```
[org.rajawali3d.materials.Material] Could not compile vertex shader:
 Shader log: Vertex shader compilation failed.
ERROR: 0:7: '=' : Syntax error:  syntax error
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

This is how it's look like when I launch my application
[image]

When I scroll up and Scroll down again:
[image]

Comment: Any updates on this? I've got similar issues using Rajawali with a RecyclerView in version 1.1.777 ...

Comment: Faced similar issue, found workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56936915/5599807